# ¿Cómo funciona el clr en .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo la duda de como funciona en si el proceso de compilación,y he estado investigando pero no entiendo bien.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué es concretamente lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Osea cuando c# compila Obtiene un archivo Intermediate Language, primero ese intermediate language es un exe o source code?. Segunda pregunta, el clr convierte ese Intermediate Language a native language pero quien ejecuta la app?

Comment: No es un .exe ni source code. El código fuente (source code) que tu programas en c# es transformado en un lenguaje ensamblador orientado a objetos que es el CIL y este a su vez, transformado en código nativo (el ejecutable). También puede ser ejecutado directamente, pero sin generar un ejecutable. La ventaja de esto es que lo hace independiente de una plataforma específica.

Comment: Quien ejecuta la app final es el procesador de la computadora.

Comment: entonces el clr simplemente convierte a CIL a nativo? osea el que ejecuta no es el clr sino el procesador?

Comment: Así es, el CLR convierte el CIL a nativo para el sistema operativo.

Comment: Nitido!!! Muchas gracias man!! excelente ahora si entendi!